# Is there a way to use condition variables to sleep, when there is only one type of thread?

Tags: c

In one of my courses, my professor asks us to implement a small program that spawns 5 threads and use a mutex to check if it's the threads respective turn. However, he also requested that we use a condition variable to avoid busy waiting for their turn.

From first glance this doesn't make much sense to me, because we cannot guarantee that any signal is going to wake up the correct thread. It seems like this is bound to be a deadlock unless the infinitely unlikely scenario occurs that the correct sleeping thread is woken up every time. Am I missing something?

Comment: "he also requested that we use a condition variable to avoid busy waiting". Which part of your program is busy waiting? Using a mutex means it is not a busy wait.

Comment: But yes, you can use condition variables to implement what has been described. You can't guarantee which thread wakes up from the signal but what you can gurantee is that only one thread will be woken up at a time. The important point is that when a thread wakes up it should re-test the condition it is waiting on.

Comment: Well there has to be an interim period. For example, with a mutex it would be:
lock
while(not my turn)
unlock
do something

I guess he is saying that this while loop is technically busy waiting. Would you acheive this by constantly signalling after exiting each critical region? I am not really sure how it would work besides what I outlined, which hasn't seemed to work for me

Comment: Put the `lock` inside the loop. Then it is not a busy loop. `do { lock } while (not my turn); unlock;`

Comment: I would do this, and I like that answer far more than using condition variables, but he specifically asked for them. It is really weird to me that he did.

Comment: A mutex is used when you want to execute something immediately after wakeup. Condition variable is used to wake everyone up and only have one (or more) continue to execute whilst the rest go back to sleep. So, yes your prof has a point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your professor gave you the necessary information to complete the task.

> From first glance this doesn't make much sense to me, because we cannot guarantee that any signal is going to wake up the correct thread.

Yes, the setup you are thinking of is used when you don't care which thread is waked up, e.g. when you have a worker pool and you just need a free thread, any free thread to assign the work to.

But if you think about it you can see you can create setups with locks and condition variables that result in your desired behavior, i.e. waking up a specific thread.

Hint: a condition variable has [`notify_all`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_all)

Hint: or, alternatively, you can have more than 1 condition variable.

Think a bit about it and try different things.